# where is Pluglet in ibm rsa 9?

Tags: rational-rsa

I'm using ibm rsa 9. In ibm knowledge center I found how to create pluglet:

1. Customize your perspective.
2. Click Window > Customize Perspective.
3. In the Customize Perspective window, click the Shortcuts tab and be
   sure New is specified in the Submenus list.
4. In the Shortcut Categories list, select Pluglets to enable the
   related shortcuts. Make sure that the Pluglet and Pluglets Project
   check boxes are checked in the Shortcut list.
5. Click the Commands tab. In the Available command groups list, select
   Pluglets and Modeling.
6. Click OK.
7. Click File > New > Pluglets Project to start creating the pluglets
   project.

Unfortunately, I don't see Pluglet in the Shortcut Categories list.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with this : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21590669.

To resolve the problem, you have to add new capabilities :

1. Open the Preferences window by clicking Window > Preferences.
2. Open the General node, then open the Capabilities page
3. Enable pluglet development: On the Capabilities page, click the Advanced button. The Advanced Capabilities Settings window opens. Expand the Development node, then select the Pluglet Development option

Hope this could help !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's recommended not to provide link only answers, can you please add at least summary of the content of the link ?